# JButton is not the selected component but changes to the the recently added button values

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm working on a small UI builder for a school project and I am able to change a button's text value from a `textField` using `DocumentListener`.

However, upon trying to add another button, I found out that as I select on the new button, it changes back to the value of the recently selected component.

```
//DragListener: for isolating changes on a particular component
DragListener drag = new DragListener(UIBuilder.this);

//Add new button on mouseclick
addButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        JButton button = new JButton("JButton");
        button.setBounds(50,20, 90,20);
        internalFrame.getContentPane().add(button);
        button.addMouseListener(drag);
        button.addMouseMotionListener(drag);
        repaint();
        System.out.println("Button added.");
    }
});
```

The component is then passed to `DragListener`

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter
{
    Point location;
    MouseEvent pressed;
    private UIBuilder uiBuilder;

   public DragListener(UIBuilder ui){
    this.uiBuilder = ui;
   }

   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
   {
       pressed = me;
       Component component = me.getComponent();

       if (component instanceof JButton){
           JButton button = (JButton) component;
           uiBuilder.getTxtFieldsetText().setText(button.getText());
           uiBuilder.getTextFieldName().setText(button.getName());

        uiBuilder.getTxtFieldsetText().getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

        @Override
        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            ((JButton) component).setText(uiBuilder.getTxtFieldsetText().getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            ((JButton) component).setText(uiBuilder.getTxtFieldsetText().getText());
        }

        @Override
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
            ((JButton) component).setText(uiBuilder.getTxtFieldsetText().getText());
        }
    });
       }
   }

   public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me)
   {
       Component component = me.getComponent();
       location = component.getLocation(location);
       int x = location.x - pressed.getX() + me.getX();
       int y = location.y - pressed.getY() + me.getY();
       component.setLocation(x, y);

    }
```

As I'm having trouble how to title and describe this problem...I'm not quite sure how to explain my problem further, so I guess I'll just put up this [image: gif] for anyone reading to understand better.

Comment: Well, you don't seem to be removing the `DocumentListener`, which could present an issue in the future

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be getting the text from the `JTextField`, but get it from the `DocumentEvent` itself

Comment: You should also limit exposing UI components to other parts of program, what reason does `DragListener` have modifying the state of the text fields. It should only be able to get and set various properties, which are then managed internally by the other class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't seem to be removing the `DocumentListener` when `mousePressed` is called again.

Have a look at your code...

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me)
{
   pressed = me;
   Component component = me.getComponent();

   if (component instanceof JButton){
       JButton button = (JButton) component;
       uiBuilder.getTxtFieldsetText().setText(button.getText());
       uiBuilder.getTextFieldName().setText(button.getName());

       uiBuilder.getTxtFieldsetText().getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
           //...
```

When `mousePressed` is called, you set the `UIBuilder`s properties with the properties of the button, but since the `DocumentListener` hasn't been removed from the last button yet, it updates the previously selected button's text automatically.

You need to change the concept slightly.  The `DragListener` should register itself as an observer of `UIBuilder` which should then generate events to which the `DragListener` can respond.  In this way, you de-couple of the code, but also reduce possible mistakes like this one.

You would then maintain a reference to the selected component and, when notified by the `UIBuilder`, update it's state accordingly.

This is likely going to mean you're going to need to generate your own listener interface(s) and event model, but since you're use to dealing with `MouseListener` and `DocumentListener`, you already have a basic understanding of how these work

## Example...

Start with a basic interface which describes the events which the builder can generate

```
public interface UIBuilderListener extends EventListener {
    public void componentTextDidChange(ComponentTextEvent evt);
    public void componentNameDidChange(ComponentTextEvent evt);
}
```

There could be more then one listener, each dedicated to a particular series of events, but I'm just keeping it simple.

The object events handlers are passed information about the event, for example...

```
public class ComponentTextEvent extends EventObject {

    private String text;

    public ComponentTextEvent(UIBuilder source, String text) {
        super(source);
        this.text = text;
    }

    public UIBuilder getBuilder() {
        return (UIBuilder) getSource();
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

}
```

Then your `DragListener` will register interest in been notified about these changes...

```
public class DragListener extends MouseInputAdapter implements UIBuilderListener {

    Point location;
    private UIBuilder uiBuilder;
    private Component selectedComponent;

    public DragListener(UIBuilder ui) {
        this.uiBuilder = ui;
        ui.addBuilderListener(this);
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
        selectedComponent = me.getComponent();
    }

    @Override
    public void componentTextDidChange(ComponentTextEvent evt) {
        if (selectedComponent instanceof JButton) {
            JButton btn = (JButton) selectedComponent;
            btn.setText(evt.getText());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void componentNameDidChange(ComponentTextEvent evt) {
        if (selectedComponent instanceof JButton) {
            JButton btn = (JButton) selectedComponent;
            btn.setName(evt.getText());
        }
    }

}
```

This is pretty vanilla (which is good), we want the `DragListener` to know as little about the `UIBuilder` as possible, this de-couples the code and allows you to change the way that the builder (or `DragListener`) work without adversely affecting each other, as they rely on what the APIs describe and not on how they are implemented (I'd personally make `UIBuilder` a interface as well, but that's me)

Then, in the `UIBuilder`, you'd register the `DocumentListener` against the `JTextField` themselves...

```
JTextField componentTextField;
componentTextField.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

    protected void generateTextEvent(DocumentEvent e) {
        try {
            Document doc = e.getDocument();
            generateTextEvent(doc.getText(0, doc.getLength()));
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            // Handle possible exception
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        generateTextEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        generateTextEvent(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        generateTextEvent(e);
    }
});
```

Which would eventually end up calling...

```
protected void generateTextEvent(String text) {
    ComponentTextEvent evt = new ComponentTextEvent(this, text);
    // Loop through listener register and call componentTextDidChange
}
```

which would perform the actual dispatching of the event

Comment: alright at least you've pointed this out to me. I'll try to read up and fix it as you've explained. Not really used in dealing with the two actually.

Comment: @Reiion The observer pattern is a pretty basic concept, one which used extensively by Swing (AKA listeners)

Comment: I have a question I hope you can help a little more. If I implement the observer pattern -- let's say I've created another listener for the textfield (value) observed in UIBuilder my problem would be connecting the selected component that can only be determined by the DragListener (because its the selector of the button component). Even though I create a ChangeListener connected to textfield (value) in UIBuilder the referencing would still be determined on DragListener

Comment: You should create some kind of listener interface which is made available through the `UIBuilder` itself (or more then depending on your needs).  The `DragListener` would the register itself to the `UIBuilder` so it can be notified when events it's interested in are generated. The `DragListener` should have NO concept of HOW the `UIBuilder` works, only that it provides a service/information and generates events

Comment: Thanks! haha liked the part where you left me some parts I needed to fill in the blanks!